# Parsing fails for everything between brackets and ips

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parsing, awk

Trying to parse a couple files quickly and cannot seem to be able to combine what I am trying to pull from the log files. I am trying to pull the date and IP addresses from log files and write them to a new log file. Log file resemble:

```
some info[28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700] 192.168.58.98 Some Other random information
--information--[28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700] 192.168.56.10 Some Other random information
192.168.58.1 [28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700]information 192.168.58.0 Some Other random
sometext:192.168.58.2 [28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700] information
```

Not every line in the file will contain the IP address first or the date first...although the date is definitely in brackets.

The code I have tried so far has been:

```
cat log_file | awk -vRS="]" -vFS="[" '{print $2]' >> New_Log_File
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" log_file >> New_Log_File
```

This pulls the date or IP perfectly fine although I need to be able to pull both at the same time and write them to the new log file. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `grep -o` combined with `awk` to parse your output:

```
grep -iEo '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+|[0-9]{2}/[a-z]{3}/[0-9]{4}(:[0-9]{2}){3} -[0-9]+|$' file |
awk -F '\n' -v RS= '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
   if ($i ~ /-[0-9]{4}/) dt=$i; else ips = (ips != "" ? ips OFS $i : $i);
   print dt " :: " ips; dt=ips=""
}'

28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700 :: 192.168.58.98
28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700 :: 192.168.56.10
28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700 :: 192.168.58.1 192.168.58.0
28/Dec/2016:04:05:58 -0700 :: 192.168.58.2
```

1. First `grep` is used to grab all date-time stamps OR ip addresses
2. Then `awk` is used to go through the parsed output and separate date and ip addresses.

Comment: as soon as I get back to my server I will let you know. Thank you!